# head and tail labels overlap the arrow

Tags: graphviz

In the following code, the head and tail labels overlap the arrow, which I do not want. What do I have to do?

```
digraph G {
    node [shape = "record"];

    edge [
      arrowhead = "normal"
      headlabel = "0..*"
      taillabel = "longlabel"
    ];


    N1 [ label="N1"];         
    N2 [label = "N2" ];       

    N1->N2;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't really control the position of head and tail-labels as it is possible for the edge label (using `labelangle`, `labeldistance`, etc.)

However, as a hack, you could **add whitespace** to the head/tail-label and that way force the center of the label to be on the left or right of the label text:

```
  headlabel = "        0..*"
  taillabel = "longlabel             "
```